# Is it really necessary to call delete on this pointer

Tags: c++, memory-management

I have a pointer to a very large static array of objects that don't have any destructors nor they inherit from any class. This array is allocated at the beginning of the program and never allocated/relocated again (by design). This array needs to be destroyed only at the very end of the program. Do I really need to call delete for the array, or is it OK to let the OS (Windows) clean up? Deleting delays exiting of program by 5-10sec. Without calling delete, OS will do that for us and program exits immediately.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199117/discussion-on-question-by-jacek-zabrzowski-is-it-really-necessary-to-call-delete).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You don't necessarily have to free the allocation at shutdown if you can assume that your program runs within a modern operating system. If it significantly reduces the time of shutting down the program, it may be an option worth to consider.

Not freeing the allocation does however have the downside that memory leak detection tools will detect this intentional leak making their use problematic. As a solution, I would suggest  making the leak toggleable so that you can run a non leaking version with detection tools, and use the leaking version in production.

Comment: It did down vote this; because, although you are presumably right for OP's situation, in general, non-typical OS'ses, external devices, network connections, graphics memory, it will lead to real problems. A note of caution would be suited.

Comment: I like the idea of toggling the behavior mainly because it allows you to try both and measure if there is actually a noticeable difference. I expect the difference will not be measurable even for gigantic arrays, since they are trivial.

Answer (score 2):

In general, it is a bad idea to let os to clean up.
I assume that nothing bad will happens, but in the future you may use your code in another program, and you will have to change things.

bottom line - free everything that you allocated.

Answer (score 2):

You should free it; for the following reasons:

- its easy, and takes minimal effort
- its good practice. Taking shortcuts too often will bite you somewhere sometime
- it sets an example for other people reading your code
- it protects you against issues. Trusting to OS to clean it up means you trust your application to exit properly. If this does not happen, the memory release will be stalled
- it protects you from yourself: in the future you might have memory in a hardware device reserved. This might not be freed by the os. So to be clear: not *all* memory is always be freed by the OS.

... these are just *some* reasons to clean up your mess ;-) ... besides... you might want to deside to put the stuff in an actual class. Then, the cleanup code is already there.

Also note: not releasing memory is one of the most common runtime issues around. Only for that reason its wise to be strict upon it.

Comment: "Trusting to OS to clean it up means you trust your application to exit properly" You are plain wrong. Windows guarantees that all memory allocated by your program will be freed independently of the way your program exited.

Comment: as I've mentioned, array is static and needs to be static. Putting in into class won't solve that. You are talking about examples from book where everything is straight simple and easy. Real life programs are never like it.

Comment: @JacekZabrzowski: obviously you don't understand. If you have a hanging thread your application will not exit at all and your OS will not free the memory, because the application doesn't exit.

Comment: @JacekZabrzowski: and, yes, real life is difficult. And professional programming is hard. Not cleaning up your mess will make it harder. If your cleanup procedures are that difficult you probably messed up in the first place. It's simple: reserve memory -> free memory. This is not about text-books. It's about being a professional.

Comment: Obviously you don't understand. If one has hanging thread one needs to make sure that the thread is not hanging and application is exiting properly. That is completely different and more serious issue. And completely unrelated to this particular case.

Comment: No it's not, because, if you work with multiple people on a program it's not always clear such a bug is introduced and therefor it makes sense to apply a defensive strategy. Next to this: if your memory is beyond the scope of your OS; something which is possible when using specific hardware devices: you'll end up needing to reboot the device to free it. This is at least as serious as the hanging thread.

Comment: You are not reading mate. Windows is OS. It has complete control over memory.

Comment: Not the memory on external devices. Not all your graphics memory is managed. Not all your TCP/IP connections will be closed properly. Not all .... I am just saying: maybe in your case... if you have an big set of `int`'s it's ok. But when a beginner reads this and trust the magic OS to clean up everything: that's wrong .... oh, and I am a purist ;-) .... I've just seen to many failing code due to this kind of stuff.

Comment: Being purist is something students are straight after college :-). Reality is completely different and unless you are lucky that you work only with POC then you have to deal with reality and real problems and not rules prescribed in books.

Comment: also you are not reading mate. I didn't say is it OK to not delete in general, I've asked about that very specific example. Read again my OP.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but not for the reason you think.

Although in general it goes somewhat against "good practice", it is perfectly "OK" to just exit and let the OS clean up, since there is nothing to be done. Objections such as "it's a bad idea, evil things may happen, resources oh the woes, whatever" are not well-founded insofar as what really happens is that your process ceases to exist, and so do the memory pages that the OS had allocated for it, and that's just it. So, as long as you are 100% positive that nothing needs to happen in your destructor, there is no reason to ever deallocate, except to make tools like valgrind (and auditors, if applicable) happy.

**However**, the fact that `operator delete[]` takes 5-10 seconds indicates that this is not the case at all. Something does happen there.

On my desktop, deleting millions of objects takes pretty much "zero" time as long as the destructors are not *very very* un-trivial. I'm saying such a funny thing as *"very very un-trivial"* since trivial (and non-trivial) destructor is a term which means something very specific and indeed a "not very very un-trivial" non-trivial destructor call is still very fast.

Wrote a quick 15-liner to test. Structure defintion with some data, default contructor zero-initializing data, and a trivial destructor. A `main` function which allocates 100 million objects, iterates over the array and updates each element with the value of `argc` (to prevent the compiler from optimizing the whole thing out), and finally deleting the array.

Runtime overall: 0.2 seconds give or take 50 millis. The same program but with a non-trivial destructor that conditionally updates a global counter takes 0.3 seconds total. Mind you, that's allocation, construction, and iteration included.

So, obviously you *are* doing something which is not at all trivial. Lots of nested virtual destructor calls on sub-objects? Deallocations from within the object's destructor? Zeroing out or otherwise touching gigabytes of memory? Closing file handles?
Impossible to tell what, but there must be *something* that is happening, or it wouldn't take so long.

So... *no* it's not OK to just quit. Because there's something that's happening, and it won't happen if you skip the delete.

Comment: Nothing is happening. Like I've said, there are no destructors, nor inheritance. You cannot compare example you wrote in 5 mins to app that had been developed for last 20 years and say that your results are representative. It is simply silly.

Comment: "Yes, but not for the reason you think." I think about exact reasons you've mentioned. And I also listed them in my OP. So saying something and then contradicting yourself in the very next sentence is not really wise.

Comment: Well, if there are no destructors and no inheritance, then your figures are more or less impossible, unless you have a 25 year old computer, or you process more than, I dunno, 10 _billion_ objects... or your dataset is so huge you run on virtual memory. You're not by any chance compiling with a memory debugging lib, or worse yet, running inside a debugger, are you? If a memory debugger checks each and every location upon deletion, then of course this might very well take 5-10 seconds, but that's no surprise then.

Comment: @Damon is right. I write progs that allocate gigs at startup, and deallocate them at close down in milliseconds. If they take 10 seconds it is because I've written a bug and one of my supposedly no-op destructors is doing something (or rather 100 million of them are).